# How do i detect a keyword but fetch the entire link?

Tags: python

So right now i have this:

```
messages = r.text

if 'metalabs' in messages:
    print('Success!')
else: 
    print('rip')
```

so if, for example the link was https://test.metalabs.io, how would i be able to set that link to a variable if the keyword was only metalabs?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a dictionary:

```py
urls = {'metalabs':'https://test.metalabs.io'}

similar = input('Keyword: ')
print(urls.get(similar, 'rip'))
```